# What is "Strike Mode" in android development

Tags: android

Hi I come across this term "strike mode" in a test about android development.

I don't remember what it mean, and I can't find it on Google, can someone explain it to me please, thank you!

Comment: What is the text of the question exactly?  I don't think this exists.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I think I need to double check the question. I will let you guys know after I confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you meant "Strict Mode"

if so, then it allows you to enable verifications of various problems in your code, for example:

- doing Flash I/O on UI thread
- doing network requests on UI thread (althought since Android 3.0 you will always get NetworkOnMainThreadException even without Strict Mode)
- leaking SQLite cursor

you can configure it so that Android will throw exception/log or show error dialog, when you violate one the configured rules.

for more look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html

Comment: I think `NetworkOnMainThreadException` only kicked in automatically with 4.0. And, it comes from `StrictMode` itself, which is automatically used to apply `penaltyDeath()` to network I/O on the main application thread. That's why you see the occasional "workaround" that reconfigures `StrictMode` to not throw the exception, which works but is really dumb. All that being said, I agree with your guess as to what the OP is referring to.

Comment: I confirmed it with a classmate, it's "STRICT MODE" not "strike mode", thank you!